# Should the small DC motors be connected in series or parallel?

Tags: batteries, motor, dc-motor

I have beginner motors kits, and I'm trying to build a car. All wheels are working and moving, but when they touch the floor, they stop. Seems like they don't have enough energy/power.

I tried with 2 AA batteries and with 4 AA batteries, and both options don't work.

Will it work better if I connect each motor directly to four AA batteries (AKA parallel)?

Or maybe add some more batteries?

What is the problem? Why is it not moving when it's on the floor?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

After reading all the answers (And I learned a lot) I tried to play with it before taking it apart. In the end, I found that
the issue was that not all the wheels exactly pointed the same direction (As you see in the picture above). As you can see, a little bit of touch and it's working.

[image]

Comment: what is stopping you from trying the motors with parallel connections?

Comment: if it is not moving when on the floor and moving when on the air it means indeed that the power provided is too low. Can you provide more details about this kit ? Motors reference ? Simple schematic draft?

Comment: This is the kit https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B08J45LPM2?psc=1&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_title

Comment: Parallel. But you'll also need to gear those motors down about 10:1 to have a realistic hope of it working.

Comment: You might be able to make a belt reduction drive by using a rubber band on the motor shaft and around the wheels, but you may need to build up the shaft with some shrink tubing to provide some friction. Another fun idea would be to put propellers on the motors like a horizontal land based quadcoptor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You pretty much always want to connect motors in parallel. Imagine if the more force you applied with one leg while walking, the faster the other leg would move. That's motor in series.

Your problem is the motors probably produce enough power, but all that power in speed instead of torque. This is usually the case with electric motors. So if the wheels did spin as fast as the motor wants them to (like when how it spins when the wheels do not touch the ground), the car would move too fast, but they cannot spin at all because they don't have enough torque.

So what you need to do is to reduce the RPM and turn all that excess RPM into torque in the process. One way to do that is a gearbox, which you do not have. But you have wheels, and wheels play into it too.

What moves the car is the force at the edge of the wheel.  What happens is that when the motor tries to turn the wheel, it produces a force on the edge of the wheel which is applied to the ground. Due to Newton, the ground applies an equal and opposite reaction by means of rolling friction. Rolling friction is a type of static friction which means that it will produce an equal and opposite force against whatever force is applied, but only up to a limit. If the wheel cannot produce enough force at the edge of the wheel to overcome this limit, then the force of rolling friction is equal and opposite to the wheel edge force produced by the motor and nothing moves.

But if the motor can produce enough force at the edge of the wheel to exceed the maximum amount of rolling friction the ground can apply, then there is excess force leftover which is then used to accelerate the car and the wheel turns.

But a motor does not produce force. It produces torque and needs a lever to convert the torque into a force. A wheel is a round lever, or a lever that has been duplicated an infinite number of times and arranged all around a shaft.

A big wheel means a longer lever which means the force applied by the ground at the edge of the wheel produces a much larger torque at the center of the wheel which the motor must overcome. So use smaller wheels. *Much* smaller wheels in this case.

And just like a lever where it can turn lots of movement with low force into small amounts of movement with high force, adjusting wheel size does the same thing. A larger wheel will move the robot farther per rotation (and thus travel faster at the same RPM) but require more torque, whereas a smaller wheel will move the robot less per rotation (and thus travel slower at the same RPM) but requires less torque.

Comment: Very interesting and good explanation. Thank you. You can see my update how I solved it in the end

Comment: The series motor connection is fundamental point in the rail transport.

Answer (score 7):

As DKNguyen says, these toy brushed motors rotate fast, but have little torque. A gearbox is needed to drive the axle. Driving the wheel axle directly without an intervening gearbox requires a motor having considerable torque...and the wheel should have as small diameter as possible.

There **is an alternative** to a gearbox, and that's *rim drive*. The surface speed of the motor's small-diameter shaft is just about right for a vehicle robot. But its diameter is far too small.
So rest the motor shaft against a vehicle wheel as shown in the photo. It helps if the vehicle wheel is slightly softer rubber. If your wheel is hard-plastic, wrap it with an elastic band, and rest the motor's shaft on that.
When placed on the ground, the motor should not stall, but will only slow down. If you have a *need for speed*, then use another motor, wired **in parallel** to drive the other wheel in a similar way.
[image: motor shaft rests on a vehicle's drive wheel]

Comment: Also basically how tank tracks work. Real tank tracks where the drive sprocket is smaller than the track height.

Answer (score 2):

*Should the small DC motors be connected in series or parallel?*

Electronic parts are connected in series to have the same current flowing through them, possibly with different voltage drops across them. They are connected in parallel to have the same voltage applied across them, possibly drawing different current from the supply.

With the brushed DC motors, each motor will draw a current from a voltage supply rail that is commensurate with the mechanical load it is trying to overcome by delivering torque.

The higher the mechanical load, the higher the current it draws. Its current range is between no load (lowest current) and stalled (highest current). It will draw its stall current at start-up as it tries to start spinning. No-load may refer to the motor having nothing on its shaft or the system (driven gears or whatever) having no load on it.

From this, brushed DC motors are unsuitable for series connection unless all motors will have the same mechanical load on their shaft at all times.

Applications for brushed DC motors in series this aren't the general case and yours certainly isn't one. Each motor will have some difference in load to the others. But they won't be able to draw different currents in a series circuit.

They'd work best powered in parallel. The motors will be able to deliver more torque to the load. But they will try to draw more current from the supply to do it and the supply may not have it.

Comment: It can give the functionality of a differential if the motors one side side of the vehicle are in series with the equivalent one on the other side; both motors will provide the same torque.  Usually on small scale vehicles this can be ignored but the tires will have to skid while turning corners as the outside one has to travel further.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal brushed DC motor, voltage and speed are proportional, as are current and torque.

Putting the motors in parallel will give them the same voltage, which means they will tend to run at the same speed. Usually for a vehicle this is what we want.

However, your car won't move, which means it's lacking torque, and therefore current at each motor. The power supply you are using is not capable of supplying the large current that each motor needs to provide the torque to move the car. With motors in parallel, the supply needs to provide 4 times the individual motor current.

Therefore in your case, you need to connect the motors in series, to reduce the current the supply has to provide. This will reduce the maximum speed the car can go at, but compared to your present zero, that's not a problem.

With motors in series, they all provide the same torque, and their relative speed can vary. If one wheel leaves the ground, then it can spin, reduce the series current, and leave the other motors producing little torque.

In order to keep all the wheels on the ground, you need at least one of

- an accurately built car on a very flat surface
- one or two pivoting axles
- a 3-wheeler that always sits stably on the ground

Comment: That’s exactly what happened. Only one moves until I made it more aligned.